# Good online Dvorak touch typing training

Tags: webapp-rec

What are some good, as in effective learning tool, Dvorak touch typing training applications on the web?

Are there any such applications aimed towards programmers?

Comment: If you could clarify what you mean by "good", that would be helpful.  Otherwise this is pretty subjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I learned Dvorak several years ago, I used [ABCD:  A Basic Course in Dvorak](http://gigliwood.com/abcd/lessons/).

It is very low key, nothing flashy.  However, I found that because I wasn't focusing on flashy gimmicks, I was focusing on the typing.  Seems like that is how it should be.  It took me a couple days to get to a passable typing speed, and about another week to get back to my normal typing speed.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I think I used that ABCD course when I was learning Dvorak - in 1998. Guess that proves you really don't need all the gimmicky stuff - just sit down and start typing.

Btw Dvorak and programming don't go perfectly together. You may wish to google a bit for modifications of dvorak that are easier to code with.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.powertyping.com/dvorak/typing.html

I'm a Programmer, I think you are suggesting that we need may need more mastery of the non alphabetic characters. True, but the above tutorial covers the whole layout and I have decided to do this. I am typing this out with Dvorak layout right now as a matter of fact and though painfully slow I am sceptical about a hybrid approach working any better. I'm gonna see if I can hang in there. The above link is pretty good.